# Python program is producing incorrect output

Tags: python, windows

Beginner with python here.

Just wrote a simple program but the output is incorrect. I must be missing something very basic.

Example input data :

```
Prody
1000000
3000
```

The output is:

```
Hi Prody
The property price is:  1000000
The estimated rental cost for the property is:  3000
The price to rental ratio for the property = 27
This is an expensive property.
```

But the output should be:

```
Hi Prody
The property price is:  1000000
The estimated rental cost for the property is:  3000
The price to rental ratio for the property = 27
This property is a bit expensive.
```

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Code:

```
information = {'name': '0', 'cap': 0, 'rent': 0}

print "First you need to provide some information."
information['name'] = raw_input("What is your name?")
information['cap'] = raw_input("What is the cost of the property?")
information['rent'] = raw_input("What is the estimated rent for the property?")

print "\n"
print "Hi", information['name']
print "The property price is: ", information['cap']
print "The estimated rental cost for the property is: ", information['rent']
print "\n"

class Property(object):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class Overpriced(Property):
    def testprice(self):
         print "The price to rental ratio for the property =",
                int(information['cap']) / (12 * int(information['rent']))

        if tprice > 40:
            print "This is an expensive property."
        elif (tprice > 25) and (tprice < 40):
            print "This property is a bit expensive."
        else:
            print "Testing."

tprice = Overpriced()
tprice.testprice()
```

Thanks for comments, changed last part to:

```
class Overpriced(Property):
    def testprice(self):
        rental_ratio = int(information['cap']) / (12 * int(information['rent']))
        print "The price to rental ratio for the property =", rental_ratio

        if rental_ratio > 40:
            print "This is an expensive property."
        elif (rental_ratio > 25) and (rental_ratio < 40):
            print "This property is a bit expensive."
        else:
            print "Testing."

tprice = Overpriced()
tprice.testprice()
```

Comment: do you realize what value`tprice` holds ? `tprice` is an object which is assigned to `Overpriced()`. Use different variables.

Comment: How can you compare a ``class instance`` to a value?

Comment: thanks for revising initial post @sammy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had computed the value, and printed it, but later on you didn not use it. This fix will make it work:)

```
class Overpriced(Property):
def testprice(self):
     computed_price = int(information['cap']) / (12 * int(information['rent']))
     print "The price to rental ratio for the property =",computed_price


    if computed_price > 40:
        print "This is an expensive property."
    elif (computed_price > 25) and (computed_price < 40):
        print "This property is a bit expensive."
    else:
        print "Testing."

tprice = Overpriced()
tprice.testprice()
```

Comment: It seems to work now:) You should look about variable names, and you should be ok:)